# Typescript, Firebase: Can't add product to cart by reading hexstring of nfc tag id

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, nfc, angularfire2

So what I'm trying to do here is add a product to my cart where the tagid of the product is equal to the hexstring of an nfc tag im reading in.

I have the correct hexstring of the tag saved into my firebase but it's not adding the product to cart when tested in app.

Can supply more code if necessary

```
this.cartService.addProduct(this.product == 
this.db.collection('products', ref => ref.where('tagid', '==', 
this.nfc.bytesToHexString(event.tag.id))));
```

Comment: The question looks incomplete and generic as it doesn't speak about what exactly the problem is. Please improve the question by adding more details. Are the stored ID and ID from the tag received upon the tap are same?

Comment: Yes, the stored ID and the ID from the tag are the same.